# How to execute shell command get the output and pwd after the command in Python

Tags: python, bash, shell, subprocess, pwd

How can I execute a shell command, can be complicated like normal command in bash command line, get the output of that command and pwd after execution?

I used function like this:

```
import subprocess as sub

def execv(command, path):
    p = sub.Popen(['/bin/bash', '-c', command],
                    stdout=sub.PIPE, stderr=sub.STDOUT, cwd=path)
    return p.stdout.read()[:-1]
```

And I check if user use `cd` command but that will not work when user use symlink to cd or other wierd way to change directory.

and I need a dictionary that hold `{'cwd': '<NEW PATH>', 'result': '<COMMAND OUTPUT>'}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I redirect stdout to stderr of pwd command. if stdout is empty and stderr is not a path then stderr is error of the command

```
import subprocess as sub

def execv(command, path):
    command = 'cd %s && %s && pwd 1>&2' % (path, command)
    proc = sub.Popen(['/bin/bash', '-c', command],
                     stdout=sub.PIPE, stderr=sub.PIPE)
    stderr = proc.stderr.read()[:-1]
    stdout = proc.stdout.read()[:-1]
    if stdout == '' and not os.path.exists(stderr):
        raise Exception(stderr)
    return {
        "cwd": stderr,
        "stdout": stdout
    }
```

**UPDATE**: here is better implemention (using last line for pwd and don't use stderr)

```
def execv(command, path):
    command = 'cd %s && %s 2>&1;pwd' % (path, command)
    proc = sub.Popen(['/bin/bash', '-c', command],
                     env={'TERM':'linux'},
                     stdout=sub.PIPE)
    stdout = proc.stdout.read()
    if len(stdout) > 1 and stdout[-1] == '\n':
        stdout = stdout[:-1]
    lines = stdout.split('\n')
    cwd = lines[-1]
    stdout = '\n'.join(lines[:-1])
    return {
        "cwd": cwd,
        "stdout": man_to_ansi(stdout)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `subprocess.Popen`, you should get a pipe object that you can `communicate()` for the command output and use `.pid()` to get the process id. I'd be *really* surprised if you can't find a method to get the current working directory of a process by pid...

e.g.: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-report-current-working-directory-of-process.html

Comment: I try it, there is /proc/<PID>/cwd directory that the code need to check, it can do this using `ls` or `file` (and parse result) but when code execute those commands cwd is not readable anymore because process ended. So you need to add sleep command after executed command. Better is to just run pwd.

Answer (score 1):

To get output of an arbitrary shell command with its final cwd (assuming there is no newline in the cwd):

```
from subprocess import check_output

def command_output_and_cwd(command, path):
    lines = check_output(command + "; pwd", shell=True, cwd=path).splitlines()
    return dict(cwd=lines[-1], stdout=b"\n".join(lines[:-1]))
```